# Post data with jquery to php file that downloads svg file

Tags: php, jquery, svg

I'm having problems with a code that is supposed to generate a svg file to download, without saving one on the server itself. I've managed to get to a point where file gets downloaded with some code in it, but not the actual $data itself.

So, cutting unnecessary things out, html button launches the javascript...

```
<button type="button" onclick="toSVG()">Save SVG</button>
```

which posts prepared data to a php file...

```
var data = $svgDiv.html();
$.post('./saveSVG.php', 
        {'data': data},
        function(data){ 
            window.location = 'saveSVG.php';
        }
);
```

that should save diagram.svg to harddrive..

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
$file = "diagram.svg";

header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");

echo('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>' . "\n"); 
echo('<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20000303 Stylable//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/03/WD-SVG-20000303/DTD/svg-20000303-stylable.dtd">' . "\n");  
echo $data; ?>
```

but downloaded diagram.svg contains only first two echoes, and $data is empty.

In browsers "Network access" window I've noticed that saveSVG.php appears twice, and in POST method status is set to OK and $data is echoed correctly, while in GET status is set to 'canceled' even though i've just downloaded the file (with empty $data ofc..)

I just don't GET it :)
Can somebody help me to understand why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you make a post call to saveSVG.php **with** post data:

```
$.post('./saveSVG.php', 
    {'data': data},
```

And after that request returns the response you want (the `data` in `function(data){`) you redirect to saveSVG.php **without** the post data: `window.location = 'saveSVG.php';`

So the second call, your actual download, is empty.

Try it this way (no $.post at all):

```
window.location = 'saveSVG.php?data=' + $svgDiv.html();
```

And in your php:

```
$data = $_GET['data'];
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it will work.. someday. I had to remove .serialize() method, because I'm trying to send raw svg tags in my $data, and i'm getting error at some point while rendering downloaded file. I need to find out yet if the problem lies in my svg tags or is because of removal of the .serialize() method.. Why you added it in the first place?

Comment: No the serialize() was just incorrect in the first place. I removed it. ;) Your remaining problem should be posted in another question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I thought about it yesterday, but checked today... What can I do, when my url created with GET method exceeds server limits?

Comment: Ah well, then you probably have to use post (or set the limit up but i don't think that's a good idea). I would use a form for the svg data and then submit it via jquery. Could you post the html part containing the svg data?

Comment: Actually it's generated by the user via some kind of editor, so I can post only an example, but they are just raw svg tags. When i'm using few objects everything works fine, until my diagram get's a bit more complicated. I expect them to be very large, so post will be the only way and I need to use one text field for it. Could help me how to achieve this? I saw this idea already yesterday, but i coudn't get it to work..

Comment: Just add the text field to your question.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer, your answer here was really useful to understand my problem.  I now have the GET method working, but my SVG data is too large to use this way.  When using the POST method, my data makes the round trip to the server, is processed by PHP and returned to the console log, but the .svg file is not created.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't have the time right now to dive back into it. So you have to get help from somebody else. Good luck anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled badly with a similar problem.  The GET method in the solution above worked for small data, but not on my fullsize data.  Changing to JQuery AJAX `.post()` as in the OP gave me exactly the same problem as the OP - the server-side php code was running, but not giving me a saved file.  I finally realised that AJAX is exactly what I DON'T want in this situation.

My solution is a simple form, with a hidden field to contain the data to be POSTed.  The value of the hidden input is "0" when the page is loaded, but is replaced with the SVG data by javascript code at the onsubmit event.
This is the form:

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="save_php.php" onsubmit="DoSubmit();">
<input type="hidden" name="post_data" value="0" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save SVG"/>
</form>
```

On my page, the SVG code I want a copy of is displayed in a `<div>` with `id="live_svg"`.  This is the javascript code which adds the code to the hidden input value at the onsubmit event :

```
<script>
// Submit the form with post data
function DoSubmit(){
  document.myform.post_data.value = $('#live_svg').html();
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Finally, the server-side PHP just reads the $_POST, and sets content headers to output the file ready for saving:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST["post_data"];
$file = "diagram.svg";

header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");

echo('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>' . "\n"); 
echo('<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20000303 Stylable//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/03/WD-SVG-20000303/DTD/svg-20000303-stylable.dtd">' . "\n");  
echo $data;
?>
```

I am embarrassed to admit how long this took me to figure out!  But I couldn't have done it without the OP, and the answer above.  Thanks!